# SharePoint Default SearchBox Seach always place # in front of search term

Tags: search

Using the default search box webpart, if you ran another search keyword for the second time, It would append the newer keyword with anchor (#) and will keep the old search keyword in the query string with key "k".
If search for first time, it appends "#" instead of "?" at the beginning of the search term.

e.g. searchresults/Pages/results.aspx?k=blash&#k=blash2
e.g. searchresults/Pages/results.aspx#k=blash2

But if search using the site search box, it actually reload the page, with "?" before the new search term.

How can I get the same behaviour when I using default search webpart, so I am not going to get something like '#'?

Comment: As far as I know, this is the default of SharePoint. Are you facing a problem with this approach? Or is the problem, that you "just" have an ugly url?

Comment: Have you tried turning off MDS?